# Problemas añadiendo atributos a un array de objetos

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando dentro de la función changeEventStatus agregar un atributo isJoined a verdadero o falso, dependiendo de si el usuario ya está en ese evento o no. Lo que he pensado hacer hasta ahora es primero filtrar entre 2 matrices y luego comparar el elemento de la matriz original con el elemento de la matriz filtrada usando una condición.

El problema es que si bien el condicional funciona, solo toma 1 elemento como verdadero y agrega el atributo como verdadero, dejando todos los demás elementos en la matriz como falsos. En la matriz filtrada hay 2 objetos, por lo que debería devolver una matriz con 2 elementos verdaderos dentro de sus atributos.

```
// React
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

// Chakra-ui
import {
  SimpleGrid,
  Box,
  Center,
  Text,
  Stack,
  Button,
  Spinner,
  Flex,
  useToast,
} from '@chakra-ui/react';

// Supabase
import { supabase } from '../../client';

const EventCard = () => {
  const toast = useToast();
  const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);
  const [isJoining, setIsJoining] = useState(false);
  const [eventId, setEventId] = useState(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getEvents();
    console.log('llama hijo')
    changeEventStatus();
  }, []);
  
  const getEvents = async() => {
    const { data, error } = await supabase
    .from('events')
    .select('*')
    setEvents([...events, ...data]);
  }

  const toaster = () => {
    return(
      toast({
        title: '¡Event Message!',
        description: "You already participate in this event.",
        status: 'error',
        duration: 3000,
        isClosable: true,
      })
    )
  }
  
  const isUserParticipateInEvent = async(userId, eventId) => {
    let { data: event_participants, error } = await supabase
    .from('event_participants')
    .select('*')
    .eq('participant_id', userId)
    .eq('event_id', eventId)
    if(event_participants.length > 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  const joinToEvent = async(id) => {
    const user = supabase.auth.user();
    let userId = user.id;
    let eventId = Number(id);
    
    setEventId(id);

    const participant = {
      participant_id: userId,
      event_id: eventId
    };

    let isParticipating = await isUserParticipateInEvent(userId, eventId);

    if(!isParticipating) {
      try {
        setIsJoining(true);
        const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from('event_participants')
        .insert([participant]);
        if(error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      } catch(err) {
        console.log('Error trying to join the event ', err);
      } finally {
        setIsJoining(false);
      }
    } else {
      toaster();
    }
  }

  const changeEventStatus = async() => {
    const user = supabase.auth.user();
    const userId = user.id;
    const { data: event_participants, error } = await supabase
    .from('event_participants')
    .select('*')
    .eq('participant_id', userId)

    const { data:eventData, error:dataError } = await supabase
    .from('events')
    .select('*')
    
    let eventParticipantIds = event_participants.map((ep) => ep.event_id);
    let filteredEvents = eventData.filter((event) => eventParticipantIds.includes(event.id));
    console.log('filtered ', filteredEvents)

    eventData.map((evt) => {
      filteredEvents.map((filteredEvent) => {
        console.log('filt ', filteredEvent.id)
        console.log('event ', evt.id)
        console.log(filteredEvent.id === evt.id)
        if(filteredEvent.id === evt.id) {
          evt['isJoined'] = true;
        } else {
          evt['isJoined'] = false;
        }
      })
    });

    console.log('new event data ', eventData)
  }

  return(

    events.map((event, ix) =>{
      return(
        <Box key={ix} p={4} rounded='sm' border='1px' borderColor='gray.100' boxShadow={'sm'}>
          <SimpleGrid display='flex' alignItems='center' justifyContent='space-between' columns={2}>
            <Box>
              <Stack>
                <Text fontSize={'2xl'} fontWeight='600'>{event.title}</Text>
                <Text>{event ? event.description : 'No description provided'}</Text>
                <Text>{`Organizer: ${event?.creator}`}</Text>
              </Stack>
              <Box pt={4}>
                <SimpleGrid columns={{sm: 1, md: 2}}>
                  <Box><Text fontSize={'small'}>{`20 participants`}</Text></Box>
                  <Box><Text fontSize={'small'}>{`Date: ${event.start_date}`}</Text></Box>
                </SimpleGrid>
              </Box>
            </Box>
            <Box>
              <Button bg='green.200' onClick={(e) => joinToEvent(event.id)}>
                {(isJoining && (eventId === event.id)) ? 'Joining...' : 'Join'}
              </Button>
            </Box>
            <Box>
              {(isJoining && (eventId === event.id)) && <Spinner />}
            </Box>
          </SimpleGrid>
        </Box>
      )
    })
  )
}

export default EventCard;
```

Datos de los arrays:

```
eventData array que llega desde el servicio
[
  {
    "id": 82,
    "user_id": "e31cb09b-7a63-4581-9e3c-19f4730641bc",
    "title": "Nuevo evento",
    "description": "en estos dias",
    "created_at": "2022-09-17T20:42:42.452948+00:00",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-17T20:42:42.452948+00:00",
    "start_date": "2022-09-23",
    "end_date": null,
    "longitude": -32.9296,
    "latitude": -71.2944,
    "creator": "rmi@mail.com",
    "place_name": null
  },
  {
    "id": 95,
    "user_id": "e31cb09b-7a63-4581-9e3c-19f4730641bc",
    "title": "Virginia",
    "description": null,
    "created_at": "2022-09-17T21:13:40.728779+00:00",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-17T21:13:40.728779+00:00",
    "start_date": "2022-09-17",
    "end_date": null,
    "longitude": 35.4867,
    "latitude": 101.902,
    "creator": "rmi@mail.com",
    "place_name": null
  },
  {
    "id": 96,
    "user_id": "e31cb09b-7a63-4581-9e3c-19f4730641bc",
    "title": "3",
    "description": null,
    "created_at": "2022-09-17T21:19:52.677742+00:00",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-17T21:19:52.677742+00:00",
    "start_date": "2022-09-17",
    "end_date": null,
    "longitude": -10.1511,
    "latitude": -75.3111,
    "creator": "rmi@mail.com",
    "place_name": null
  },
  {
    "id": 97,
    "user_id": "e31cb09b-7a63-4581-9e3c-19f4730641bc",
    "title": "event",
    "description": "At indonesia beach",
    "created_at": "2022-09-17T21:34:53.360125+00:00",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-17T21:34:53.360125+00:00",
    "start_date": "2022-09-17",
    "end_date": null,
    "longitude": -6.17555,
    "latitude": 106.827,
    "creator": "rmi@mail.com",
    "place_name": "Indonesia"
  }
]

array desde filtered events
[
  {
    "id": 82,
    "user_id": "e31cb09b-7a63-4581-9e3c-19f4730641bc",
    "title": "Nuevo evento",
    "description": "en estos dias",
    "created_at": "2022-09-17T20:42:42.452948+00:00",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-17T20:42:42.452948+00:00",
    "start_date": "2022-09-23",
    "end_date": null,
    "longitude": -32.9296,
    "latitude": -71.2944,
    "creator": "rmi@mail.com",
    "place_name": null
  },
  {
    "id": 95,
    "user_id": "e31cb09b-7a63-4581-9e3c-19f4730641bc",
    "title": "Virginia",
    "description": null,
    "created_at": "2022-09-17T21:13:40.728779+00:00",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-17T21:13:40.728779+00:00",
    "start_date": "2022-09-17",
    "end_date": null,
    "longitude": 35.4867,
    "latitude": 101.902,
    "creator": "rmi@mail.com",
    "place_name": null
  }
]

array eventParticipantIds
[82, 95]

   El nuevo array luego de el ultimo map
[
  {
    "id": 82,
    "user_id": "e31cb09b-7a63-4581-9e3c-19f4730641bc",
    "title": "Nuevo evento",
    "description": "en estos dias",
    "isJoined": false,
    "created_at": "2022-09-17T20:42:42.452948+00:00",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-17T20:42:42.452948+00:00",
    "start_date": "2022-09-23",
    "end_date": null,
    "longitude": -32.9296,
    "latitude": -71.2944,
    "creator": "rmi@mail.com",
    "place_name": null
  },
  {
    "id": 95,
    "user_id": "e31cb09b-7a63-4581-9e3c-19f4730641bc",
    "title": "Virginia",
    "description": null,
    "isJoined": true,
    "created_at": "2022-09-17T21:13:40.728779+00:00",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-17T21:13:40.728779+00:00",
    "start_date": "2022-09-17",
    "end_date": null,
    "longitude": 35.4867,
    "latitude": 101.902,
    "creator": "rmi@mail.com",
    "place_name": null
  },
  {
    "id": 96,
    "user_id": "e31cb09b-7a63-4581-9e3c-19f4730641bc",
    "title": "3",
    "description": null,
    "isJoined": false,
    "created_at": "2022-09-17T21:19:52.677742+00:00",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-17T21:19:52.677742+00:00",
    "start_date": "2022-09-17",
    "end_date": null,
    "longitude": -10.1511,
    "latitude": -75.3111,
    "creator": "rmi@mail.com",
    "place_name": null
  },
  {
    "id": 97,
    "user_id": "e31cb09b-7a63-4581-9e3c-19f4730641bc",
    "title": "event",
    "description": "At indonesia beach",
    "isJoined": false,
    "created_at": "2022-09-17T21:34:53.360125+00:00",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-17T21:34:53.360125+00:00",
    "start_date": "2022-09-17",
    "end_date": null,
    "longitude": -6.17555,
    "latitude": 106.827,
    "creator": "rmi@mail.com",
    "place_name": "Indonesia"
  }
]
```

```js
const arr1 = [
  {
    "id": 82,
    "user_id": "e31cb09b-7a63-4581-9e3c-19f4730641bc",
    "title": "Nuevo evento",
    "description": "en estos dias",
    "created_at": "2022-09-17T20:42:42.452948+00:00",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-17T20:42:42.452948+00:00",
    "start_date": "2022-09-23",
    "end_date": null,
    "longitude": -32.9296,
    "latitude": -71.2944,
    "creator": "rmi@mail.com",
    "place_name": null
  },
  {
    "id": 95,
    "user_id": "e31cb09b-7a63-4581-9e3c-19f4730641bc",
    "title": "Virginia",
    "description": null,
    "created_at": "2022-09-17T21:13:40.728779+00:00",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-17T21:13:40.728779+00:00",
    "start_date": "2022-09-17",
    "end_date": null,
    "longitude": 35.4867,
    "latitude": 101.902,
    "creator": "rmi@mail.com",
    "place_name": null
  },
  {
    "id": 96,
    "user_id": "e31cb09b-7a63-4581-9e3c-19f4730641bc",
    "title": "3",
    "description": null,
    "created_at": "2022-09-17T21:19:52.677742+00:00",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-17T21:19:52.677742+00:00",
    "start_date": "2022-09-17",
    "end_date": null,
    "longitude": -10.1511,
    "latitude": -75.3111,
    "creator": "rmi@mail.com",
    "place_name": null
  },
  {
    "id": 97,
    "user_id": "e31cb09b-7a63-4581-9e3c-19f4730641bc",
    "title": "event",
    "description": "At indonesia beach",
    "created_at": "2022-09-17T21:34:53.360125+00:00",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-17T21:34:53.360125+00:00",
    "start_date": "2022-09-17",
    "end_date": null,
    "longitude": -6.17555,
    "latitude": 106.827,
    "creator": "rmi@mail.com",
    "place_name": "Indonesia"
  }
]

const arr2 = [
  {
    "id": 82,
    "user_id": "e31cb09b-7a63-4581-9e3c-19f4730641bc",
    "title": "Nuevo evento",
    "description": "en estos dias",
    "created_at": "2022-09-17T20:42:42.452948+00:00",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-17T20:42:42.452948+00:00",
    "start_date": "2022-09-23",
    "end_date": null,
    "longitude": -32.9296,
    "latitude": -71.2944,
    "creator": "rmi@mail.com",
    "place_name": null
  },
  {
    "id": 95,
    "user_id": "e31cb09b-7a63-4581-9e3c-19f4730641bc",
    "title": "Virginia",
    "description": null,
    "created_at": "2022-09-17T21:13:40.728779+00:00",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-17T21:13:40.728779+00:00",
    "start_date": "2022-09-17",
    "end_date": null,
    "longitude": 35.4867,
    "latitude": 101.902,
    "creator": "rmi@mail.com",
    "place_name": null
  }
]

arr1.map((evt) => {
  arr2.map((filteredEvent) => {

    if(filteredEvent.id === evt.id) {
      evt['isJoined'] = true;
    } else {
      evt['isJoined'] = false;
    }
  })
});

console.log(arr1);
```

Comment: Podrias incluir un ejemplo de los datos a comprar, si bien muestras la funcion "changeEventStatus" quedan bastantes dudas sobre como son los objetos como para saber en que estas herrando o como podria mejorar.

Comment: Hola, alli pude agregar informacion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en esta anidacion de `map`, no tiene sentido tu logica

```
eventData.map((evt) => {
  filteredEvents.map((filteredEvent) => {
    console.log('filt ', filteredEvent.id)
    console.log('event ', evt.id)
    console.log(filteredEvent.id === evt.id)
    if(filteredEvent.id === evt.id) {
      evt['isJoined'] = true;
    } else {
      evt['isJoined'] = false;
    }
  })
});
```

Lo ideal es hacer una comparacion boolean directamente en el primer `map`

```js
const events = [
  {
"id": 82,
"title": "Nuevo evento",
  },
  {
"id": 95,
"title": "Virginia",
  },
  {
"id": 96,
"title": "3",
  },
  {
"id": 97,
"title": "event",
  }
];

const userEventsIDs = [82, 95];

const eventsUpdated = events.map(item => ({...item, isJoined: userEventsIDs.includes(item.id)}))

console.log(eventsUpdated);
```

Comment: Hola arturo!, gracias por la respuesta..de verdad me estaba complicando de mas con el anidado y era mejor hacer directo el map y agregar el atributo con el includes en el mismo!